# Firestore iOS - Why does my array get printed out multiple times?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm successfully able to display a users friends array in a table view, but when I print out the array it get's printed out 3 times instead of 1 time, how do I fix this?

Friend System model:

```
    var removeFriendListener: ListenerRegistration!

    func addFriendObserver(_ update: @escaping () -> Void) {
        removeFriendListener = CURRENT_USER_FRIENDS_REF.addSnapshotListener{ snapshot, error in
            self.friendList.removeAll()
            
            guard error == nil else {
                #if DEBUG
                    print("Error retreiving collection")
                #endif
                return
            }
            for document in snapshot!.documents {
                let id = document.documentID
                self.getUser(id, completion: { (user) in
                    self.friendList.append(user)
                    update()
                })
            }
            
            if snapshot!.documents.count == 0 {
                update()
            }
        }
    }

    func removeFriendObserver() {
        removeFriendListener.remove()
    }
```

Friend System View Controller:

```
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        
        FriendSystem.system.addFriendObserver { () in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
            print(FriendSystem.system.friendList)
        }
    }
```

Array printed out

```
[App.User]
[App.User, App.User]
[App.User, App.User, App.User]
```

Comment: Because you are calling the closure every iteration of your loop. Call it after the loop only.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson What would the code look like for that

Comment: Replace `if snapshot!.documents.count == 0 { update()}` with `update()` only

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Why do I get an empty array when I do this?

Comment: I have no idea, maybe you did it incorrectly.

Comment: It prints out three times because there are three friends? `for document in snapshot!.documents`. Also, you've got DispatchQueue which you really don't need as any calls made within the Firebase closure are done on the main thread. There's a lot of extraneous code that that could just be removed for simplicity - you don't need the completion handler at all based on the code. We also don't know what this `self.getUser` does so it could also be an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should not call your update() here:-

```
for document in snapshot!.documents {
            let id = document.documentID
            self.getUser(id, completion: { (user) in
                self.friendList.append(user)
                update()
            })
        }
```

instead you should call it after the for loop gets completed.

Comment: And where would the new "call" go?

Comment: @C.Agu as suggested in comments you can call  `update()` after for loop ends there's no need of `if snapshot!.documents.count == 0 {
                update()
            }`

Comment: Hi @AppDev, when I do this I get back an empty array, why is that happening?

Comment: because it might get called before the for loop has completed try having a breakpoint at update() and check